# How to achieve this in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, sublimetext2

I saw the feature shown and described below in Sublime Text and was curious to know how does one achieve it in Emacs?

[image: What I want to achieve in Emacs]

**A brief description of the feature:**

Have a condensed view of the *entire* code/text file currently opened and highlight the region, in the very same condensed view, which is currently being viewed. Clicking on any part of the condensed view would bring that part in focus.

Although I know, almost certainly, that I would rarely use this feature since it would be, in my view, a estate hog, considering the fact that I have even had my `scroll-mode` disabled, but still I am curious to know how it can be done in Emacs.

And yeah I went through(skimmed) Sublime's feature list to find the name of the feature, so that I could then try to find it for Emacs, but couldn't. Therefore, another question: What's this feature called?

*Original [source](http://i1-linux.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/Sublime-Text_1.jpg) of the image above.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [MiniMap](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MiniMap) package. From EmacsWiki:

- Put minimap.el in your load path.
- `(require 'minimap)`
- Use <kbd>M-x minimap-create</kbd> in a buffer you’re currently editing.
- Use <kbd>M-x minimap-kill</kbd> to kill the minimap.
- Use <kbd>M-x customize-group</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>minimap</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> to adapt minimap to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Mirrored it for our FAQ: https://answers.launchpad.net/python-mode/+question/231580